# Como usar o Top Langs no Git Hub

Tags: git, github

Alguém sabe me dizer como usar o !Top Langs no github para exibir as linguagens que estão sendo mais usadas por mim, no meu repositório do perfil?

Answer (score 1):

Basta apenas criares um repositório com o nome igual ao username do github, depois crias um ficheiro chamado `readme.md` e lá dentro apenas colas este código:

```
![TOP Linguagens](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=UTILIZADOR&layout=compact&theme=dracula)
```

substituis `UTILIZADOR` para o username do teu github!

Tens aqui o meu exemplo: https://github.com/13dev/13dev

Podes personalizar tudo, vê a documentação aqui: https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats/